# What is the path to access the downloaded artifacts in the release pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a `.zip` file as part of my published artifacts.
In my release pipeline, I am using a 'Powershell Script Task'. I need the path 
to this zipped folder in my script.

When release pipeline is triggered, it copies over the artifacts:
[image]

Path to zipped folder: `d:\a\r1\a\_DLR FOI\drop\packedSolution\dlrFoiSolution_managed.zip`

How do I get the folder path `d:\a\r1\a\_DLR FOI\drop\` in my PowerShell script?

`$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)` only returns upto `d:\a\r1\a`.

Comment: i havent done that in a while, but isnt `a_DLR FOI` build name? or release name? so its effectively hardcoded?

Comment: '_DLR FOI' would be the build pipeline name.
Trying to avoid recreating the URL dynamically.

Comment: since a_DLR Foi is a build name. use the following path : "$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)\$(Build.DefinitionName)\drop* "

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_DLR FOI/drop/packedSolution/dlrFoiSolution_managed.zip
```

That should point to the release definition's artifact directory d:\a\r1\a . More variables [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch), or just add a suitable task (like copy) to release definition in editor, browse through the linked artifacts, and copy the path there.

Comment: Using the build definition variable is smart, as Amit suggested.